# Is Wikipedia correct about desarguesian projective planes being self-dual?

Tags: projective-geometry

I stumbled over a statement on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28projective_geometry%29 and would like to ask how this could possibly be true. It states the following

> The projective planes $PG(2,K)$ for any division ring $K$ are self-dual.

Is this really true? Or rather: What is wrong with the following argument that (if correct) would contradict the statement:

For a finite dimensional left vector space $V$ over a division ring $K$, we have the dual left vector space $V^{\star}$ over $K^{op}$ (the opposite division ring of $K$). Now, it is certainly true that $P(V^{\star})$ is isomorphic to the dual of $P(V)$. Thus, $P(V)$ is isomorphic to its dual if and only if $P(V) \cong P(V^{\star})$. Since $V$ and $V^{\star}$ have the same dimension, does that not necessarily imply that $K$ and $K^{op}$ are isomorphic by the Second Fundamental Theorem of projective Geometry?

In fact, isn't $PG(2,K)$ (or $PG(n,K)$ for any $n \geq 2$) being self-dual simply eqvuialent to $K \cong K^{op}$ (which is of course is not always the case). I also recall that I have read this somewhere.

So, to put it in one line: What is wrong? The statement on Wikipedia or my reasoning?

---

EDIT: I found some course notes in which it is also claimed that $PG(n,K)$ is self-dual iff $K$ is self-dual (see 6.1 in http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/pps/pps6.pdf). This does contradict what Wikipedia says, doesn't it?

Comment: Your reasoning is very convincing. I think it's a good rule of thumb that when something in Wikipedia looks wrong, and not just at first glance, then it probably is.

Comment: Looking at the history of the article, that sentence appears to have been introduced by User:Wcherowi on September 25, 2011.  
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Duality_%28projective_geometry%29&diff=next&oldid=452275155
You can also write directly to the interested user on his/her talk-page (link from the above revision)


Comment: Thanks for the comment Tom and for your suggestion, Pietro. However, what I still would like to have is a definite answer to my original question. There are surely people on this board who know projective geometry well enough to decide whether PG(2,K) being self-dual really is equivalent to $K \cong K^{op}$ (contradicting the wikipedia article) or not.

Comment: I can't say I've ever gone through the proof, and I didn't know that it went by one of those opaque numerical names ("Second Theorem of ..."), but I'm sure that there is a theorem to the effect that a division ring can be constructed (up to isomorphism) from the projective plane that it determines. So I am sure you are right.

Comment: Doesn't Desargues imply Pappus? In which case assuming K is not commutative gives a contradiction.  Gerhard "Or Does Pappus Imply Desargues?" Paseman, 2012.11.25

Comment: Pappus implies Desargues (Hessenberg's theorem). The converse is not true. A Desarguesian projective geometry is of the form $PG(2,K)$ where $K$ is a division ring and Pappus holds if and only if $K$ is commutative.  

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are right. There is a theorem that asserts that if two projective spaces $P(V,F)$ and $P(V',F')$ are isomorphic then the skew fields $F$ and $F'$ are isomorphic. Thus if $P(V,F)$ and $P(V^*,F^{op})$ are isomorphic then $F\cong F^{op}$ as skew fields.

I recommand these course notes "Essential Concepts of Projective Geometry" available here (the author gives a lot of references):
http://math.ucr.edu/~res/progeom/
in particular look at appendix C.

Comment: David -- re "There is a theorem that asserts that...": do you have a reference?

Comment: This is theorem IV.17 of "Essential concepts of projective geometry", the author gives a lot of references among them:
chapter 6 of R. Hartshorne. "Foundations of Projective Geometry". Benjamin, New York, 1967. 